# can't use Http Post method in android application

Tags: android

HI,

I need to use http post method for web-service in android application .But in android shows error when use this method .How to use this method in application or any other equal method for replacing this http post method.

thanks,
Lakshmanan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
URL url = new URL(my_ip_address);           
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setRequestProperty("METHOD", "POST");
HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection)connection;
int responseCode = httpConnection.getResponseCode();

        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
  //do your stuff
}
```